# How to override and log requests before routes.RouteExistingFiles happened?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm very new at MVC and so I'm not sure if this even makes any sense.

From what I read, by default routes.RouteExistingFiles=false, which means MVC will check if a request is a file already existed on disk (such as images, css, etc) If so, serve it. If not, check the route tables etc.

So how do I log those requests? Write a static class? Overwrite an httpmodule? Httphandler?

I simply want to debug the requests and help myself understand MVC 4 better.

Many thanks.

Edit:

Btw, I already installed Glimpse, but it doesn't seem to be able to log all requests such as the images as they were served directly and do not need to participate in the routing.

Comment: I think you should be able to do this in the filter RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.

I think I can do away with custom urlrouting httpmodule as described here

http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/10/13/optimising-asp-net-mvc3-routing

Thanks!!